# Event typeahead:rendered not working on twitter typeahead

Tags: twitter, typeahead

I'm using the twitter typeahead library. Version: 0.10.4
I have been able to bind events to the "opened", "selected" events but nothing happens when I bind the event "rendered", although it is in the documentation.
Has any of you guys come across this issue?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
typeAhead.on('typeahead:selected', function(e, suggestion) {
            alert(0);return; // Shows the alert
        })
    typeAhead.on('typeahead:rendered', function() {
// Nothing happens
        });
```

Comment: Of course, by nothing happens I mean nothing happens when the results are rendered. Instead, when selecting one of the results, the alert does popup. Guess it's a problem with the event naming? I guess the documentation may be for version 0.11, which is not available through a cdn so I can't use that one. Also, the rendered event handler DOES have an alert in my code. I just removed it by accident when I simplifed the code for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, debugging I've found out this line

```
typeAhead.data().ttTypeahead.dropdown.datasets[0].onSync('rendered', function(){
  console.log('rendered');
});
```

it's working for me and I aint found any better than this, without modifying typeahead libraries.

if you have more datasets, just change to a for loop.

Comment: So that code is in the typeahead js library? Could you tell me what you modified in the library? Thanks a lot!

Comment: At the time I posted the code, I haven't modified the library, so it worked with native typeahead

Answer (score 0):

I'm having troubles with this event too. I'm using version 0.11.1 and as far as I can see I think there's a kind of bug when passing arguments to the callback function:

if you use this handler:

```
function(obj, matches) {
   console.log(matches);
}
```

you seem to get only one (the first one, of the several matched suggestions.

if you use this handler:

```
function(obj, match1, match2) {
   console.log(match1);
   console.log(match2);
}
```

you get two, and so on.

Actually all suggestions are passed as this handler prove:

```
function() {
   console.log(arguments);
}
```

skipping the first slot, the remaining are the current suggestions, so I think this is a bug of the plugin.